# Deriving the first moment of Collisionless Boltzmann Equation in Spherical Polar Coordinates

Tags: galactic-dynamics, stellar-dynamics

I am following these notes: [Dynamics and Astrophysics of Galaxies](http://astro.utoronto.ca/%7Ebovy/AST1420/notes/notebooks/05.-Equilibria-Spherical-Collisionless-Systems.html).

After equation 6.37, we have:
\begin{equation*}
    p_r\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{p_\theta}{r^2}\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} +
    \frac{p_\phi}{r^2\,\sin^2\theta}\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}
    -\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} r}-\frac{p_\theta^2}{r^3}-\frac{p_\phi^2}{r^3\,\sin^2\theta}\right)\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_r}
    +\frac{p_\phi^2\,\cos\theta}{r^2\,\sin^3\theta}\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_\theta} = 0\,.\\
\end{equation*}

This is the Collisionless Boltzmann Equation in Spherical Polar Coordinates.

Then

> We now multiply this by $p_r$ and integrate over all $(p_r,p_{\phi},p_{\theta})$ using
> that $\mathrm{d}p_r\,\mathrm{d}p_\phi\,\mathrm{d}p_\theta = r^2\,\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}v_r\, \mathrm{d}v_\phi\,\mathrm{d}v_\theta$ and using partial integration to deal
> with the derivatives of f with respect to the momenta

\begin{align}\label{eq-spher-jeans-penult}
    \frac{\partial (r^2\,\sin\theta\,\nu\,\overline{v^2_r})}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial (\sin\theta\,\nu\,\overline{v_r\,v_\theta})}{\partial \theta} & +
    \frac{\partial (\nu\,\overline{v_r\,v_\phi}/\sin\theta)}{\partial \phi}\\
    &
    +r^2\,\sin\theta\,\nu\,\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} r}-\frac{\overline{v_\theta^2}}{r}-\frac{\overline{v_\phi^2}}{r}\right) = 0\nonumber\,.
\end{align}

I would like to arrive to this result myself. Multiplying the SPC CBE by $p_r$ & going ahead with the suggested volume element, considering the *first* term in the above equation, not being worried about the integration limits gives us:

\begin{equation}
\int p_r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} p_r r^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}v_r \mathrm{d}v_{\theta} \mathrm{d}v_{\phi}
=\int v_r^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} r^2 \sin \theta \mathrm{d}v_r \mathrm{d}v_{\theta} \mathrm{d}v_{\phi}
=r^2 \sin \theta \int v_r^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \mathrm{d}v_r \mathrm{d}v_{\theta} \mathrm{d}v_{\phi}
\end{equation}

Using 6.32 from the mentioned notes,

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial (r^2\,\sin\theta\,\nu\,\overline{v^2_r})}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \sin\theta \int v^2_r f \mathrm{d}v_r \mathrm{d}v_{\theta} \mathrm{d}v_{\phi} \right)
\end{equation}

Which is not equal to what I have found just a line above.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Some question on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3968607/590567) & [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604530/212053).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correspondence with the author of those notes, I arrived at the following conclusion.

When we do $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$, we require that all other (other than $r$) variables which f is dependent on, are held constant. That is: $\theta, \phi, p_r, p_{\theta}, p_{\phi}$ are constants.

Note that:

$(p_r, p_{\theta}, p_{\phi})=(\dot{r}, r^2 \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}, r^2\dot{\theta})$

Keep in mind that:

- $p_r$, ie $\dot{r}$ is held constant: it does not mean $r$ is held constant (in fact, we are differentiating with respect to $r$).
- $p_{\theta}$, ie $r^2\sin^2\theta\dot{\phi}$ is held constant. This does not mean that either $r$, $\theta$ or $\dot{\phi}$ is held constant.
- $p_{\phi}$, ie $r^2\dot{\theta}$ is held constant. We are not claiming this about $r$ or $\dot{\theta}$.

Writing the steps emphasizing this statement above:

$$\int d\vec{p} p_r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}  p_r \Bigr|_{\theta, \phi, p_r, p_{\theta}, p_{\phi}}$$

Writing out explicitly what we mean by $d\vec{p}$:

$$=\int \mathrm{d}(p_r,p_{\theta},p_{\phi}) p_r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}  p_r \Bigr|_{\theta, \phi, p_r, p_{\theta}, p_{\phi}}$$

**We can move out the partial differentiation because all other term than $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ is held constant: [THIS IS THE MAIN STEP]**

$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int \mathrm{d}(p_r,p_{\theta},p_{\phi}) p_r^2 f \Bigr|_{\theta, \phi, p_r, p_{\theta}, p_{\phi}}$$

Changing from the $p$-nomenclature to the variables they represent:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int \mathrm{d}(\dot{r}, r^2\dot{\theta}, r^2\sin^2\theta\dot{\phi})  v_r^2 f \Bigr|_{\theta, \phi, \dot{r}, r^2 \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}, r^2\dot{\theta}}$$

ie

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int \mathrm{d}(v_r, r \sin\theta v_{\phi},  r v_{\theta}) v_r^2 f \Bigr|_{\theta, \phi, \dot{r}, r^2 \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}, r^2\dot{\theta}}$$

This step I am unsure about (ie why I don't have a $dr$ and $d\theta$ term, for example), but we say:

$$\mathrm{d}(v_r, r \sin\theta v_{\phi},  r v_{\theta}) = r^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}v_r \mathrm{d}v_{\theta} \mathrm{d}v_{\phi}$$

Rewrite integral

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int r^2 \sin\theta \mathrm{d}v_r \mathrm{d}v_{\theta} \mathrm{d}v_{\phi} v_r^2 f$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} r^2 \sin\theta \int \mathrm{d}v_r \mathrm{d}v_{\theta} \mathrm{d}v_{\phi} v_r^2 f$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \sin\theta \nu \bar{v_r^2} \right)$$

As claimed by the notes.

---

Same answer on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3970297/590567) & [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/604848/212053).